# How can I get values of object return in android

Tags: android, json, api, gson

I would like help on getting key and value of the object return in android.

This is the json object, I want to check if the result is success then proceed else do other things.

```
{
  "product_name": "iPhone 8",
  "result": " Success",
  "error": null,
  "description": "iphone 8, the best phone",
  "agent": null,
  "client": "0700000000",
  "amount": "800$",
  "clientId": null,
  "stage": null,
  "message": " Success: YOUR AIRTIME HAS BEEN SENT TO:0727110300 Successfully.",
  "datetime": "2017-10-14 12:57:42"
}
```

this my code on android using rx java

```
                @Override
                public void onNext(Product product) {

                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    String productResponse = gson.toJson(product);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), productResponse, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (productResponse.getString("result").equals("success")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "success, ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "error, ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

Comment: I don't know if understand correctly, but why don't you directly use product instance, eg. product.getSuccess()? If you want to parse Json string and get the value, have a look at json-simple: https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/

Comment: the api is return that object, in that object there s result key which can be success or failed, i want to get the result value so that i can proceed with the next step accordingly to result value.

Comment: Doesn't the object have its own getters for its fields? When you look in the Product class or type product. , are there no methods?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
JSONObject js = new JSONObject(productResponse);
if(js.getString("result").toString().equals("Success")) {
     //Do something in case of success
}else{
      //Do something in case of error
}
```

Comment: JSONObject js = new JSONObject(productResponse);
if(js.getString("result").trim().toString().equals("Success")) {
     //Do something in case of success
}else{
      //Do something in case of error
} .       I added trim() and it worked! Thanks Baba

Answer (score 1):

Create a POJO to map your json to java class and parse it using JSon. following is the pojo.

```
public class Product {

@SerializedName("product_name")
@Expose
private String productName;
@SerializedName("result")
@Expose
private String result;
@SerializedName("error")
@Expose
private Object error;
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("agent")
@Expose
private Object agent;
@SerializedName("client")
@Expose
private String client;
@SerializedName("amount")
@Expose
private String amount;
@SerializedName("clientId")
@Expose
private Object clientId;
@SerializedName("stage")
@Expose
private Object stage;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("datetime")
@Expose
private String datetime;

public String getProductName() {
return productName;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
this.productName = productName;
}

public String getResult() {
return result;
}

public void setResult(String result) {
this.result = result;
}

public Object getError() {
return error;
}

public void setError(Object error) {
this.error = error;
}

public String getDescription() {
return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
this.description = description;
}

public Object getAgent() {
return agent;
}

public void setAgent(Object agent) {
this.agent = agent;
}

public String getClient() {
return client;
}

public void setClient(String client) {
this.client = client;
}

public String getAmount() {
return amount;
}

public void setAmount(String amount) {
this.amount = amount;
}

public Object getClientId() {
return clientId;
}

public void setClientId(Object clientId) {
this.clientId = clientId;
}

public Object getStage() {
return stage;
}

public void setStage(Object stage) {
this.stage = stage;
}

public String getMessage() {
return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
this.message = message;
}

public String getDatetime() {
return datetime;
}

public void setDatetime(String datetime) {
this.datetime = datetime;
}

}
```

Now Use it like this.

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 Product productResponse = gson.toJson(product, Product.class);
if (productResponse.getResult().equals("success")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "success, ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "error, ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

Comment: Product productResponse = gson.toJson(product, Product.class);   Yeah, I have the pojo. now I get: cant resolve symbol product.

Comment: i know its stupid to ask, but pojo class has its name as Product, right ??

Answer (score 1):

> 1.use `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(productResponse);` to parse `productResponse`
>
> 2.use `equalsIgnoreCase` to judge `String`

Try this in your code .

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String productResponse = gson.toJson(product);
Toast.makeText(getContext(), productResponse, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(productResponse);
        if (jsonObject.getString("result").equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "success, ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "error, ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
} catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```